# NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore keys cannot be set

Tags: macos, swift, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

I'm writing a bit of code to save user preferences.

```
enum CustomSettingsEnum: NSNumber {
    case Off
    case On
}

let someKey = "SOME_KEY"    

func getSettings() -> CustomSettingsEnum {
    var cseBool = Bool?
    var cse: CustomSettingsEnum!
    let settingsExists = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore().boolForKey(self.someKey)
    if settingsExist {
        // Get the NSNumber and convert that to Bool
    } else {
        cse = CustomSettingsEnum.On
    }
    return cse
}

func setSettings(cse: CustomSettingsEnum) {
    NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore().setObject(cse, forKey: self.someKey)
}
```

I'm calling `setSettings()` before ever calling `getSettings()`,
but when calling `getSettings()`, it seems `settingsExist` in `getSettings()`  is always false. Why would this be? And is this the best way of saving such info?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misunderstood the function `boolForKey` for `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`.

`boolForKey` isn't checking whether or not that key exists,
but is checking for the value of that key, which is supposed to be a Bool.

So I rewrote it like this:
enum CustomSettingsEnum: NSNumber {
        case Off
        case On
    }

```
let someKey = "SOME_KEY"    

func getSettings() -> CustomSettingsEnum {
    var cseBool = Bool?
    var cse: CustomSettingsEnum!
    let settingsExists = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore().objectForKey(self.someKey)
    if settingsExist != nil {
        // Get the NSNumber and convert that to Bool
    } else {
        cse = CustomSettingsEnum.On
    }
    return cse
}
```